# Insurance on one card. Trip on another

Tags: insurance

I bought travel insurance using one credit card and another for my trip. Will I be covered if I cancel?

Comment: Is that a standalone contract, or a credit card's travel insurance. What does the contract states?

Comment: "Will I be covered if I cancel?".  This is ambiguous.  Do you mean cancel your insurance, or cancel your trip? And what do you mean by "covered"?

Answer (score 8):

> I bought travel insurance using one credit card and another for my trip.

I have never seen an insurance policy that requires the same form of payment for the covered travel and the policy itself. But you never know: insurances are VERY creative in creating exclusions, so you need to read your actual policy document.

One possible exception are insurance benefits that come with your credit card (which you typically don't have to pay extra for). These obviously only cover travel that's been purchased with the card that offers these benefits.

> Will I be covered if I cancel?

You will be covered if you cancel for a covered reasons and if your case isn't excluded. The list of covered reasons tends to be short and the list of exclusions tends to be long. Again: you need to read your actual policy.

Comment: "These obviously only cover travel that's been purchased with the card" - typically, but not necessarily. The credit card I own covers all my travels, no matter how I paid. But still +1 because "read the policy" is the only correct answer here.